# disabling root ssh access not working

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security

By mistake I have allowed loging as root through ssh, now there are several automated attempts to log as root by some malicious machine. There are so many attempts that the server is slow and my sites are not served right. I tryed disabling the root login by editing

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

with

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

and I ran

```
sudo usermod -p '!' root
sudo passwd -l root
sudo service ssh restart
```

but the log in auth.log still shows the attempts every second
there is a way of blocking this if the attempts are made from several ips ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you use port 22 for `ssh`, so if this port is open you always get these kind of login attempts. These are mostly automated scans/dictionary attacks aiming on port 22. They will hammer your server regardless if you turned root login off because these are stupid scripts. 
All you can and should do is secure your server and monitor it constantly. Disabling root access is a good starting point and highly recommended.
You can also:

- Put `ssh` on a non standard port like 10222.
- Use a tool like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org) and block IPs with too many login attempts. There is also [DenyHosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net).

This should reduce the "background noise" for a good portion.